# Why does Slaine warp-spasm?

Tags: comics, 2000ad

In the Slaine comics, what causes him to warp-spasm in battle? Does he have any control over it happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The warp spasm is directly derived from Thomas Kinsella's translation of the Táin and used to describe the [battle-frenzy of Cúchulainn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%BA_Chulainn#The_Cattle_Raid_of_Cooley); here's the relevant extract:

> The first warp-spasm seized Cúchulainn, and made him into a monstrous thing, hideous and shapeless, unheard of. His shanks and his joints, every knuckle and angle and organ from head to foot, shook like a tree in the flood or a reed in the stream. His body made a furious twist inside his skin, so that his feet and shins switched to the rear and his heels and calves switched to the front... On his head the temple-sinews stretched to the nape of his neck, each mighty, immense, measureless knob as big as the head of a month-old child... he sucked one eye so deep into his head that a wild crane couldn't probe it onto his cheek out of the depths of his skull; the other eye fell out along his cheek. His mouth weirdly distorted: his cheek peeled back from his jaws until the gullet appeared, his lungs and his liver flapped in his mouth and throat, his lower jaw struck the upper a lion-killing blow, and fiery flakes large as a ram's fleece reached his mouth from his throat... The hair of his head twisted like the tange of a red thornbush stuck in a gap; if a royal apple tree with all its kingly fruit were shaken above him, scarce an apple would reach the ground but each would be spiked on a bristle of his hair as it stood up on his scalp with rage.

I don't apologise for the length of this quote, because it's necessary to give it in full so that you can compare with Massimo Belardinelli's original drawings of the warp spasm; one example below; you can see that it's a very faithful depiction and that the text of the Táin must have been followed when designing it.

[image: Original black and white drawing of the warp spasm]

The phrase "warp spasm" itself was a rendering of old Irish "ríastrad" and was originally used by Thomas Kinsella, but adapted by Pat Mills when writing Sláine - the collection "Warrior's Dawn" includes a 2-page essay titled "The Origins" which goes into this and more.

The [Wikipedia article on Sláine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sl%C3%A1ine_%28comics%29) is as good as anything else for answering your question; although it doesn't cite references for this specific item, it is nonetheless correct.

> He has the power of the "warp spasm", based on the ríastrad or body-distorting battle frenzy of the Irish hero Cú Chulainn, in which earth power "warps" through his body, turning him into a terrifying, monstrous figure who knows neither friend nor foe.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if he can intentionally trigger the transformation. It seems to happen when he's under duress or battle frenzy. He first transformed when he was a child being bullied.

From [ComicVine](https://www.comicvine.com/slaine/4005-50725/):

> Slaine has the ability warp spasm which warps his body and grants him superhuman strength, speed, stamina and tolerance for pain. in this form he has to control his rage or he will attack both enemies and friends.

Answer (score 1):

In the Slaine universe, the warp spasm is caused by Slaine channeling Earth power through his body. In his early adventures he was shown performing feats of strength for money (Ukko's idea no doubt) so that suggests he has some control over the transformation.

Answer (score -1):

From memory, Slaine's warp spasm is not something under his direct control. It is a natural response when the Goddess he serves has been denigrated or her people are threatened. It's a divine force that animates him in time of sacred need.

"And he killed 30 to his left, and 30 to his right. And he did not think it too many."

Mess with Danu and you will have a pile of trouble. Via Slaine MacRoth, her devotee.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  This is a usefully different answer to those that are already posted, but it could be improved if you can provide a quote that it's not under _his_ control but rather his goddess'.

Comment: This is my understanding, distilled from reading the series years ago in 2000AD. I don't have the material to hand in order to search for substantiating quotes. I may go and buy why the stories again, and we'll see what I can find at that point.Slaine was not like the Incredible Hulk. He didn't just get angry as result of personal provocation. There was always something far more to it than that. The power comes from the Earth Goddess, Danu. When it comes it has to be because she allows it, not because he's simply decided to 'turn on the tap'.